# c++ stl map storage and memory usage

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, storage

I understood that when inserting new entry, stl map will copy construct and store value instead of pointer or reference.

However, I am confused by the following sample code:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ){
    map<int, vector<int> > m;
    for(int i=0;i<10; i++){
        m[i] = vector<int>();
    }
    cout<<sizeof(m)<<endl;
    cout<<m[1].size()<<endl;
    for(map<int, vector<int> >::iterator it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); it++){
        it->second.push_back(1);
        it->second.push_back(1);
        it->second.push_back(1);
    }
    cout<<sizeof(m)<<endl;
    cout<<m[1].size()<<endl
}
```

The outputs are

```
48
0 
48  
3
```

Why the size of the map is unchanged even though I am changing the values of the map?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, if by *size* you mean the number of entries in the map, you need to use `m.size()` rather than `sizeof(m)`. The latter measures the size (in bytes) of the `std::map` object, which isn't where the actual entries are stored. So that size won't change, no matter how many entries you add.

Secondly, your code doesn't actually add any new entries to the map. It only adds entries to some of the vectors *in* the map.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As far as I understood, stl map stores value instead of pointer. i.e., when assign some object to the map, it will invoke the copy constructor to create an object in the map. However, sizeof(m)=>48, but sizeof(m[1])=>24, which means sizeof(m) is much smaller than sizeof(m[1])*m.size(). This leads me to think "m" stores pointer instead of a true vector.

Comment: @Chao Both statements are true, in a sense. Yes, it stores a pointer (because it has to: The size of the vector will change as you add and remove elements). But that pointer is not a pointer to the original vector that you passed. **Map makes a copy of that vector and then (basically) stores a pointer to that copy.** (The vector, by the way, does a similar thing internally: `sizeof(m[1])` won't change no matter how many elements you add to the vector, because the vector itself contains merely a pointer to a separate, dynamically-allocated storage, which is were the elements are located).

Comment: @jogojapan 'Map makes a copy of that vector and then (basically) stores a pointer to that copy' does that mean i can obtain the address of any value stored in a map, modify the object, and be sure I wouldn't corrupt the map in any way? IE can I be sure the map doesn't attempt to move the value around as the map itself is read from or written to in any form?

Comment: @moefear Yes, that is correct. But if there is a special case you are wondering about, maybe put the code into a new question. There may be special cases, e.g. if you declared the map as a map with constant values (e.g. `map<int,const string>` where a modification of values may not be possible.

Comment: @jogojapan no not wondering about special cases.. it's just that every time I read the part about invalidation of iterators (on cppreference.com), I get the feeling that insertions into the map end up moving the locations of preexisting values. But after all this i guess not.

Comment: @moefear Iterator invalidation may occur in `std::vector` and `std::unordered_map` when inserting or removing elements. But not in `std::map`. This is because the former two store list elements and keys in a continuous block of data, and during insert or removal, the entire block may have to be moved if it gets too small or too large. But `std::map` is stored as a tree with pointers between the nodes, so no moving of large blocks occurs.